# Guardar información de un spinner a una base de datos SQLite Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite, spinner

Estaba haciendo mi app la cual estoy en el registro de usuarios ya pude hacer que dependiendo de la información de registro  se pueda abrir con usuario y contraseña su pantalla de inicio de sesión la cual después muestra los datos almacenados en una textview y así poder modificarlos a su gusto.

Sin embargo también puse en el layout un spinner para su registro y no encuentro información acerca de cuando el usuario le de click al spinner (que lo poble con la forma de un array en strings) y que se guarde la información que seleccionó a mi base de datos que hice en SQLite para que después igualmente lo mande a un TextView (No es forzoso que después lo pueda modificar). Si me pudieran compartir un ejemplo de código o páginas ya que llevo demasiados días inténtandolo.

Esta es la creación de la BD, No se que tanto debería mostrar pero pondré lo necesario

```
public class Usuario {
    int id;
    String Nombre, Apellidos, Usuario, Contrasena, Correo, Numero, Dia, Mes, Year, Hombre, Mujer, Discapacidad;

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public Usuario(String name, String last, String user, String pass, String email,
                   String number, String dia, String mes, String year, String hombre,
                   String mujer, String disc) {
        Nombre = name;
        Apellidos = last;
        Usuario = user;
        Contrasena = pass;
        Correo = email;
        Numero = number;
        Dia = dia;
        Mes = mes;
        Year = year;
        Hombre = hombre;
        Mujer = mujer;
        Discapacidad = disc;
    }
 public boolean isNull() {
        if (Nombre.equals("") && Apellidos.equals("") && Usuario.equals("")
                && Contrasena.equals("") && Correo.equals("") && Numero.equals("")
                && Dia.equals("") && Mes.equals("") && Year.equals("")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usuario{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", Nombre='" + Nombre + '\'' +
                ", Apellidos='" + Apellidos + '\'' +
                ", Usuario='" + Usuario + '\'' +
                ", Contrasena='" + Contrasena + '\'' +
                ", Correo='" + Correo + '\'' +
                ", Numero='" + Numero + '\'' +
                ", Dia='" + Dia + '\'' +
                ", Mes='" + Mes + '\'' +
                ", Year='" + Year + '\'' +
                ", Hombre='" + Hombre + '\'' +
                ", Mujer='" + Mujer + '\'' +
                ", Discapacidad='" + Discapacidad + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
// Aqui pongo los getters and Setters, como es largo solo pondre el de discapacidad
public String getDiscapacidad() {
        return Discapacidad;
    }

    public void setDiscapacidad(String discapacidad) {
        Discapacidad = discapacidad;
    }
}
```

Mi clase Utilitys para despues obtener sus valores y mostrarlas en otras activities

```
public class Utilitys {
Context c;
    Usuario u;
    ArrayList<Usuario> lista;
    SQLiteDatabase sql;
    String bd = "BDUsuarios";
    String tabla = "create table if not exists usuario(id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            "name TEXT, last TEXT, user TEXT, pass TEXT, email TEXT, number Text, dia Text," +
            "mes Text, year Text, hombre Text, mujer Text, disc Text)";

    //Esto es para poder abrir la tabla privada
    public Utilitys(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        sql = c.openOrCreateDatabase(bd, c.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        sql.execSQL(tabla);
        u = new Usuario();
    }
//Vamos a utilizar el método insertar (Esto es para registrar usuarios en la BD)

    public boolean insertUsuario(Usuario u) {
        if (buscar(u.getUsuario()) == 0) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("name", u.getNombre());
            cv.put("last", u.getApellidos());
            cv.put("user", u.getUsuario());
            cv.put("pass", u.getContrasena());
            cv.put("email", u.getCorreo());
            cv.put("number", u.getNumero());
            cv.put("dia", u.getDia());
            cv.put("mes", u.getMes());
            cv.put("year", u.getYear());
            cv.put("hombre", u.getHombre());
            cv.put("mujer", u.getMujer());
            cv.put("disc", u.getDiscapacidad());
            return (sql.insert("usuario", null, cv) > 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 //Contar cuantos usuarios acaban de loggearse
    public ArrayList<Usuario> selectUsuarios() {
        ArrayList<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        lista.clear();
        Cursor cr = sql.rawQuery("select * from usuario", null);
        if (cr != null && cr.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Usuario u = new Usuario();

                u.setId(cr.getInt(0));
                u.setNombre(cr.getString(1));
                u.setApellidos(cr.getString(2));
                u.setUsuario(cr.getString(3));
                u.setContrasena(cr.getString(4));
                u.setCorreo(cr.getString(5));
                u.setDia(cr.getString(6));
                u.setMes(cr.getString(7));
                u.setYear(cr.getString(8));
                u.setHombre(cr.getString(9));
                u.setMujer(cr.getString(10));
                u.setDiscapacidad(cr.getString(11));
                lista.add(u);

            } while (cr.moveToNext());
        }
        return lista;
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi activity registrar, ya declare el spinner y quiereo almacenar la opción que puso y guardarla en mi BD pero me pone error

```
public class Registrar extends AppCompatActivity {
 Spinner optionsDisc;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registrar);
optionsDisc = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDisc);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.discapacidades,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        optionsDisc.setAdapter(adapter);

//Algunos de los campos que si pude lograr obtener su texto
campoMes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mesRegistro);
        campoYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.añoRegistro);
        rdHombre = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RDhombre);
        rdMujer = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RDmujer);
}

//Aqui esta el error en .getText de optionsDisc se que no es texto pero no se que poner .-.
   public void onClick(View view) {
          switch (view.getId()){

               case R.id.RegRegistrarse:
                Usuario u = new Usuario();
                u.setMes(campoMes.getText().toString());
                u.setYear(campoNumber.getText().toString());
                u.setHombre(campoNumber.getText().toString());
                u.setMujer(campoNumber.getText().toString());
                u.setDiscapacidad(optionsDisc.getText().toString());

                if (!u.isNull()) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"ERROR:Asegurate de rellenar los campos TnT",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);snackbar.show();
                }else if (util.insertUsuario(u)) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"Te has registrado correctamente :3",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);snackbar.show();
                }else{
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"Usuario ya registrado :/",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);snackbar.show();
                }

                break;

            case R.id.RegRegresar:
                Intent i=new Intent(Registrar.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

                break;

        }

}
}
```

Comment: Hola, sería conveniente que agregaras el código que has intentado hasta ahora para poder ayudarte. Revisa este hilo sobre cómo preguntar y agregar información a tu pregunta: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres guardar del `Spinner` es un valor en `String`, debes usar `getSelectedItem()` quedándote así:

```
u.setDiscapacidad(optionsDisc.getSelectedItem().toString());
```